# Error Resulting from Placing a Dynamic Variable inside of Table

Tags: dynamic, list-manipulation

I want to create a list of values, `True` or `False`, and to update those values with a `Checkbox`. But the number of elements needs to be arbitrary.

It should look something like the following code which works perfectly fine:

```
dyn={False,False,False};
A={{1,dyn[[1]]},{2,dyn[[2]]},{3,dyn[[3]]}}
Row@{Checkbox@Dynamic@dyn[[1]],Checkbox@Dynamic@dyn[[2]],Checkbox@Dynamic@dyn[[3]]}
```

But, of course, it is not practical to write out every iteration of these things. This is the reason that `Table` exists. However, when I put everything into tables, it does not work.

```
n=3;
dyn=Table[False,{i,n}];
A=Dynamic@Table[{i,dyn[[i]]},{i,n}]
Row@Table[Checkbox@Dynamic@dyn[[i]],{i,n}]
```

The code above results in this error message:

```
Part::pspec: Part specification i is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>
```

I do not understand why `Table` and `Dynamic` are in conflict with one another. It is as if `Dynamic` reaches the `i` before `Table` and replace it with an iterative value and then `Dynamic` has no idea what to do with it. But why is this? Or is the problem something else altogether?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `Module` or `With`; using these will allow you to limit the context of your counting variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the output of this:

```
Table[ Dynamic[i], {i,3}]  (* gives {i,i,i} *)
```

with this:

```
Table[ With[{i=i},Dynamic[i]], {i,3}]  (* gives {1,2,3} *)
```

Now you can use that:

```
a = Range[3];
Table[ With[{i=i}, Dynamic[ a[[i]] ] ], {i,3}]  (* gives {1,2,3} *)
```

Then:

```
a+=1;   (* changes output above to {2,3,4} *)
```

Addendum to address question in the comments below: You can look at the Attributes of a function (in this case Dynamic). If you see that it has a HoldFirst (or HoldRest, or HoldAll) attribute, then that tells you some of its arguments will not be evaluated. For example, consider:

```
Attributes[foo] = {HoldFirst};
Table[ foo[i], {i,3} ]   (* gives {foo[i], foo[i], foo[i] *)
Table[ With[{i=i},foo[i]], {i,3}]  (* gives {foo[1], foo[2], foo[3] *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That answers the question. Out of curiosity, precisely what was the problem? How can I avoid this in the future? Thanks again!

Comment: I added some info in the answer. Also this post is useful; if you read it you will likely avoid many common programming conundrums: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use MapIndexed:

```
n = 3; dyn = Table[False, {i, n}];
A = Dynamic@Transpose[{Range[n], dyn}]
MapIndexed[Checkbox[Dynamic[dyn[[#2[[1]]]]]] &, Range[n]]
```

Comment: similarly `Table[ Checkbox[Dynamic[dyn[[#]]]] &@i , {i, 3}]`

Comment: @george2079 Yes. Or, of course, just `Map[Checkbox[Dynamic[dyn[[#]]]] &, Range[n]]`