# How to write a loop

Tags: programming, dynamic

I try to create a table which will describe traffic paths at a crossroads.
Instead of using copy-paste repeatedly, I would like to write a loop.

For example:

```
Grid[{

    {Style["direction North", Bold]},
    For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, 
      {Style["traffic path", Bold], i, 

      Labeled[InputField[Dynamic[data[[i, 1]]], Hold[Expression],
      FieldSize -> 10], "Q", Left, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]], 

      Labeled[InputField[Dynamic[data[[i, 2]]], Hold[Expression], 
      FieldSize -> 10 ], "V", Left, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]],  

      PopupMenu[Dynamic[data[[i, 3]]], {1 -> "left", 2 -> "right",3 -> "straight "
               }](*popup*) 
      } (*style*)
    ](*For*) 
    }](*Grid*)
```

I do not have much experience in *Mathematica*, so this straightforwardly-written loop doesn't work. I have read the manuals, but haven't found any information.

Tell me, please, what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: the short answer to your actual question is to switch from `For[i = 1, i < 4, i++ , ...code.. ]` to `Table[ ...code... , {i,3}]`.  Getting your `Dynamic` constructs to work is another matter..

Comment: probably useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89433/2079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Table` approach:

```
data = {{66, 55, 3}, {44, 33, 2}, {22, 11, 1}};
Grid[{{Style["direction North", Bold]}}~Join~
        Table[{Style["traffic path", Bold], i, 
          Labeled[InputField[Dynamic[data[[#, 1]]] &@i, FieldSize -> 10], 
           "Q", Left, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]], 
          Labeled[InputField[Dynamic[data[[#, 2]]] &@i, FieldSize -> 10], 
            "V", Left, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]], 
        PopupMenu[
               Dynamic[data[[#, 3]]] &@i, {1 -> "left", 2 -> "right", 
                 3 -> "straight "}]} , {i, 3}]]
```

Comment: +1 `Dynamic[data[[#, 1]]] &@i` - Nifty

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = {{66, 55, 3}, {44, 33, 2}, {22, 11, 1}};

MapIndexed[(d[First[#2]] = #[[1]]) &, data];
MapIndexed[(e[First[#2]] = #[[2]]) &, data];
MapIndexed[(f[First[#2]] = #[[3]]) &, data];

Grid[Prepend[Map[Function[i,
    {Style["traffic path", Bold], i,
     Labeled[InputField[Dynamic[d[i],
        (d[i] = data[[i, 1]] = #) &], FieldSize -> 10],
      "Q", Left, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]],
     Labeled[InputField[Dynamic[e[i],
        (e[i] = data[[i, 2]] = #) &], FieldSize -> 10],
      "V", Left, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]],
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[f[i], (f[i] = data[[i, 3]] = #) &],
      {1 -> "left", 2 -> "right", 3 -> "straight "}]}],
   Range[3]], {Style["direction North", Bold], Null, Null}]]

data
```

> ```
> {{66, 55, 3}, {44, 33, 2}, {22, 11, 1}}
> ```

As values are changed in the input fields and popups the changes are reflected in `data`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt  and complete answer!